# Recommended way to test for iOS Version specific feature at runtime

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, versioning

I'm targetting IOS 4.3 and 5.0 with an app built against the 5.0 SDK and would like to add support for the Twitter functionality introduced in iOS5 only when the app runs on a iOS5 device. What is the recommended way to reliably test for the availability of these OS features at runtime without having your app crash?

I know you do this using respondsToSelector in Objective-C but how is it done in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With recent MonoTouch versions you can use the following code:

```
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (5, 0)) {
            window.RootViewController = navigation;
        } else {
            window.AddSubview (navigation.View);
        }
```

Otherwise you can get a `string` from `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion` and do some checks with your own code.

Comment: Ok while you can probably use that to assume a certain feature is there it's not really the "per feature check" that I was looking for because what did we learn from the web: Don't check for versions, test for features. But if that's the only way to do then so be it :)

Comment: If you want to check by feature you can do something like `bool feature_present = (new FeatureType ().Handle == IntPtr.Zero);` and that should work for *most* new features inside *weak* frameworks but YMMV.

Comment: With latest version it's just `if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(5, 0))` because it already returns a bool.

Comment: @redent84 you're right, that was the old (beta) API. The new one differs a bit and I updated the sample code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Follow up to comments, including mine...

If you want to check by feature you can do something like:

```
        MonoTouch.Twitter.TWRequest req = new MonoTouch.Twitter.TWRequest ();
        if (req.Handle == IntPtr.Zero) {
            Console.WriteLine ("No Twitter support before iOS5");
        }
```

What happens is that the selector to create the `TWRequest` instance will return `null` and the .NET object will be created in an invalid (unusable) state that you can query with the `Handle` property. Again YMMV, testing is key :-)

Comment: In the future it will not be possible to create such invalid objects (an exception will be thrown).