# Monotouch 5.0 and iOS 4.3 compatibility

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have got an application developed with Monotouch 4.0.7. This app is running on iPads with iOS 4.3.
Now, I want to migrate to the latest Monotouch version is 5.0. Will I be able to deploy my app on iPads with iOS 4.3? Or Monotouch 5.0 only for iOS 5.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to develop for iOS 4.3 (or even earlier iOS versions) with MonoTouch 5.0.

To set the minimum iOS version your app needs, go to the project's options, and in the `iPhone Application` page set `Deployment Target` to the minimum version.

Have in mind that MonoTouch will not tell you if you use iOS 5.0 API in your app. You can add iOS 5.0 features to your app, but you must not try to use those features on a lower version ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311284/recommended-way-to-test-for-ios-version-specific-feature-at-runtime/8311516#8311516) you can see how to accomplish this).

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade to Monotouch 5.x without any problems. In Monodevelop, change your SDK to 5.x
Just make sure your **deployment target remains 4.3**, if you still want to target that platform.
You will have to pay attention to not **calling any methods that don't exist in 4.3**.
If you want to have different/extended behavior on iOS 5 devices, you can check the OS version and use a different code branch.

Another small thing to be prepared for: iOS5 behaves differently in some situations. For instance if you are having hierarchical UIViewControllers, iOS5 will automatically call all UI events like ViewWillAppear(), even if you don't use the new UIViewControllery hierachy API.
What I want to say: test your app thoroughly on both iOS versions.

Comment: Pleasure. Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most.